# Is it possible to increase the local Vis Aura?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

I discovered my base is in an area with very low background magic, which is unfortunate.

Is there a way to grow/strengthen the nearest aura node? I know Crystal Clusters help a bit, but they can only push the background Vis to 110%, which is next to nothing in my case (80 → 88), and they generate Flux.

Comment: maybe you can move your TC base a bit and reach a larger node

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you chop down silverwood trees, you can get saplings. Plant those within 5-10 spaces from your existing node. As the tree grows, it will produce a new node in the trunk of that tree. They two nodes will merge, and the total aura will increase. I managed to get my node from 60ish up to almost 800 now this way.

Be aware, that the node will generate flux, and freak out a little each time you merge like this.

Comment: I tried this with Silverwood nodes, but they didn't merge, the old one just disappeared. Maybe it only works with certain node types though.

Comment: Yep, it seems normal node + silverwood node = bigger node. Great.

Answer (score 0):

Merging nodes from silverwood trees only increases the maximum capacity of the merged node, it does not increase the actual vis level.  It seems that other nodes (a few chunks away) send vis between each other and charge each other.  I think you need to grow at least two big nodes to have a good vis level.